# Conocer tipo de variables

Tags: java, type

Por ejemplo tengo esta variable `var`

```
int var=200;
```

Como puedo saber de que tipo es una variable (`int`, `String`, `boolean`...)?

Ya que si la imprimo no se si es un `int` o un `String` (en este caso).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `Wrappers` en vez de tipos primitivos, por ejemplo para tu caso en vez de `int` usarías `Integer`.

```
Integer var = 200;
System.out.println("Valor: " + var + ", Tipo de dato: " + var.getClass());
```

En la salida obtendrías lo siguiente:

> Valor: 200, Tipo de dato: java.lang.Integer.

Aquí te dejo una tabla de tipos primitivos y sus equivalentes en `Wrappers`:

```
Clase Wrapper  Tipo Primitivo
Integer         int
Double          double
Boolean         boolean
Byte            byte
Character       char
Long            long
Short           short
```

Answer (score 5):

Otra manera de hacerlo, sin tener que estar obligado a crear la variable con un envoltorio, sería colocando `Object` al momento de obtener el nombre de la clase, algo así:

```
int i = 1;
System.out.println(((Object)i).getClass().getName());
```

**Salida:**

```
java.lang.Integer
```

Funcionaría también para tipos no primitivos:

```
Integer mInt = 1;
System.out.println(((Object)mInt).getClass().getName());
```

**Salida:**

```
java.lang.Integer
```

---

> Para un uso más elegante o avanzado, puedes implementar la clase
>   [`FieldSpy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/example/FieldSpy.java), explicada en la documentación oficial de Java. En la
>   página de tutoriales ellos explican también [algunos ejemplos de
>   uso](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldTypes.html).